# action after scroll with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How to start counting timeout after scroll action (not while, but when scroll stops)? How to bind action **after** scroll?

$(window).scroll(function(){

```
if ( timer ) clearTimeout(timer);

timer = setTimeout(function(){
    // Make your AJAX request here...
}, 10000);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

You can use the nice jQuery plugin **Special scroll events for jQuery by James Padoley**.

Works really great.

Check out the page and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fbSbT/1/) (Just scroll ;))

#### More Information

- [Special scroll events for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/)
- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fbSbT/1/)**